# Rust - MVP Pattern implementation

Tags: design-patterns, rust, mvp

I'm trying to find the best way to implement MVP pattern at RUST Language. Actually I'm using Clean Architecture pattern and now I'm trying implement MVP pattern inside. Whats the better way to do it?

For example:
I have trait of some view:

```
pub trait ILoginView{
    fn new(presenter: LoginPresenter) -> Self;
}
```

And some presenter for it:

```
pub struct LoginPresenter{
    view: &mut dyn ILoginView,
}
```

Finally impl of view trait:

```
pub struct LoginView{
    presenter: LoginPresenter,
}

impl ILoginView for LoginView{
    fn new(presenter: LoginPresenter) -> Self {
        Self{
            presenter
        }
    }
}
```

And I don’t know how best to connect them with each other, so that the presenter, for example, changes the state of the view, and the view receives the login result.

> P.S. I think that this question will be quite useful,
> because there are practically no answers to a similar question in the
> search results for Rust Lang.

Comment: I'm not an expert on MVP, so I can't give you an actual answer; I just want to prepare you that many of the 'best practices' patterns don't work for Rust any more, due to the lifetime constraints of Rust. Whether MVP is one of them, I don't know. Just as a heads up. The reason is that Rust doesn't allow self-referential data structures, and many patterns include them. It's of course possible with reference counters, but Rust doesn't have a garbage collector, so you have to make sure you don't create circular references.

Comment: @Finomnis, looks like... Anyway, I'll try to do something about it in a couple of days, if I get any result, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

After trying to find a solution to this problem, I decided to delegate part of the logic from the Presenter to the View, and turn the Presenter into just a layer between the use cases and the View, while the Presenter does not know anything about the View and cannot communicate with it and is simply a kind of container for use cases. As for me, this approach is optimal, "best practices should simplify development, not complicate it", and in the case of Rust, the "true MVP pattern" introduces a huge number of unsafe operations and greatly complicates reading and writing code.